# Initialize the empty string in ObjectC?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Someone use the following to initialize the NSstring

```
NSString *astring = [[NSString alloc] init];
```

I am wondering why not just use

```
NSString *atring = nil or NSString *astring = @""
```

Answer (score 13):

There is no *semantic* difference between `NSString *astring = [[NSString alloc] init];` and `NSString *astring = @"";` - but `NSString *astring = nil;` is completely different. The first two produce a reference to an *immutable* string value, the last indicates the *absence* of a value.

Whether the various ways of generating an zero-length string produce different objects is entirely an implementation detail. The code:

```
NSString *a = [[NSString alloc] init];
NSString *b = [NSString new];
NSString *c = @"";
NSString *d = [NSString stringWithString:@""];
NSLog(@"%p, %p, %p, %p, %p", a, b, c, d, @""); // %p = print the value of the reference itself
```

outputs (the exact values will vary):

```
0x7fff7100c190, 0x7fff7100c190, 0x1000028d0, 0x1000028d0, 0x1000028d0
```

showing only 2 zero-length string objects were created - one for `@""` and one for `alloc`/`init`. As the strings are *immutable* such sharing is safe, but in general you should **not** rely on it and try to compare strings using reference comparison (`==`).

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *atring = nil
```

is different -- it's a nil pointer, not an empty string.

```
NSString *astring = @""
```

is almost the same, if you change it to something like

```
NSString* astring=[@"" retain];
```

It's one of the things that "don't matter"; he or she simply used one way. Probably for no particular reason at all.

Comment: You don't need to retain constant strings like `@""`.

Comment: Hm... maybe it's just an old habit, I must admit that I never checked that. I just don't like releasing stuff that I haven't retained, always makes me feel off-balance.

Comment: I don't think you have to release it either, if that makes you feel better ;)

Answer (score 2):

NSString *atring = nil; is simply setting the pointer to nil and does nothing other than ensure that pointer is set to nil;

NSString *astring = @""; is a shorthand literal and is the equivalent of [NSString stringWithString:@""];

On another point I don't know why you would want to initialize a string to nothing if its not mutable since you won't be able to change it later without overriding it.

Comment: I don't believe NSString *aString = @"" is equivalent to [NSString stringWithString:@""]; I think literal strings live in a static section of memory for the program. stringWithString: indicates the memory is allocated on the heap, IIRC.

Comment: @BrianPalma correct. You can see this in the implementation of CFString, and it's the same as will be for the new Numeric literals in Objc-3.0

Comment: Actually, `@""` *is* equivalent to `[NSString stringWithString:@""]`, because of optimizations in the Foundation framework.  It sees you're trying to create an immutable string out of an immutable string, so it short circuits and just gives you your original string back.

Comment: @DaveDeLong - I think your explanation implies that `[NSString stringWithString:@""]` *is equivalent to* `@""` and not vice-versa. Though I expect in all these answers there is some variance on the interpretation of "equivalent", "shorthand" and "identical"... ;-)