# Removing elements with same value from NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsobject

My `NSMutableArray` contains some strings as elements. One of the element is repeated many times at different indexes in the array. For example `[@"", @"1,2,3",@"",@"5,3,2,1",@""]`.
I want to remove all the elements with value `@""` from the mutable array. I tried following ways but couldn't get the solution.

1. Using For loop:

   ```
   for(id obj in myMutableArray)
   {
       if([obj isEqualToString:@""])
       {
           [myMytableArray removeObject:obj];
       }
   }
   ```
2. Using dummy mutable array called `nextMutableArray`

   ```
   for(id obj in myMutableArray)
   {
       if([obj isEqualToString:@""])
       {
           continue;
       }
       else [nextMutableArray addObject:obj];
   }
   ```

In both the ways, elements (`@""`) at other indexes are removed but not at the index 0 (first object). What could be the possible reason? Is there any way to remove all the elements that contain string `@""` from the mutable array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

one option is to filter your array using predicates:

```
NSArray *someArray = @[@"", @"1,2,3", @"", @"5,3,2,1", @""];
NSLog(@"%@", someArray);
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF != ''"];
NSArray *filteredArray = [someArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"%@", filteredArray);
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. The NSMutableArray is populated from a NSstring using componentsSeparatedByString method (seperated by \n). Hence it has @"" at every interval of other elements. I tried using predicates, sadly the result is same. The element @"" always remains at index 0 and cannot be removed. I could remove it manually (removeObjectatindex), however sometimes (very rare) there may not be @"" at index 0 during execution of the code. Hope  I'm not confusing you.

Comment: can you provide the exact content of the source string? so that i can verify what's going wrong?

Comment: For an instance of code execution, the source string  contains @"\0\×1b\n1,2,3,4,6,8,10,22\n". Here the useful string is the digits that starts from 1 and ends at 22.

Comment: is it always numbers that you want to keep in the array?

Comment: Yes. However, the number may be decimal, positive or negative. The app gets this source string from a remote server and must store in its local database.

Comment: can you try and update the predicate to the following? `NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES '^\\\\S+$'"];`

Comment: Element 0 isn't `@""`, it is `@"\0\×1b"`.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Perhaps \0\×1b indicates an end of a string in C. However it keeps on changing like \0\×1a and other forms. How can I remove it?

Comment: you could think about what are valid values for you and create a regex depending on it to filter out the rest... for example `NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES '^(\\\\d|,)+$'"];` to only allow digits and commas...

Comment: I learned more about NSPredicate from [https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html] and used a specific number as a flag while sending data from the server. Now I use the flag to filter the data. NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicteWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] 'flag'"];  The problem is solved :) 
I want to thank @André Slotta for your kind effort. Willeke's one comment become the King maker. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

No Need of For loop. Simply use this.

```
[mutableArray removeObjectIdenticalTo:@""];
```

Comment: Form the documentation of `removeObjectIdenticalTo`: "This method determines a match by comparing the address of anObject to the addresses of objects in the receiver.". Are you sure every `@""` has the same address?

Comment: @Willeke removeObjectIdenticalTo: obviously removes all the @"" value objects and each object has different address values, but the speciality of this it deals with the objects neither with the address value.

Comment: So the documentation is wrong? (How) did you test this? All literals `@""` have the same address. `[someString substringToIndex:0]` and `[NSMutableString string]` aren't removed

Comment: You should use `removeObject:`, which performs *equality* testing - i.e. objects which represent the same value, and not `removeObjectIdenticalTo:`, which performs *identity* testing - i.e. occurrences of exactly the same object. The latter *may* appear to work with `@""` but there is no guarantee that every occurrence of the empty string is represented by the same object - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370676/initialize-the-empty-string-in-objectc/11371533#11371533) - however the former will always work. Fix this and you have the right (and best) answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove duplicate entries from an array, You can use NSSet Class.
NSSet did not accept duplicate/s value.

```
NSMutableArray *arrTest=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"", @"1,2,3",@"",@"5,3,2,1",@"", nil];
NSSet *set = [NSSet setWithArray:arrTest];
arrTest = [[set allObjects] mutableCopy];
```

or
You can do like this:

```
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id str, NSDictionary *unused) {  return ![str isEqualToString:@""];  }];
   arrTest = [[arrTest filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]mutableCopy];
```

This is fast and simple way.

Comment: The first solution will remove all duplicates (and leave one) of every string. The order of the array can be changed.